# SQL Escaping/Sanitizing Magento Item Attribute Value Data That Is Set Programmatically?

Tags: magento, sanitization

When I programmatically set a Magento item attribute to data that the user provided, do I need to SQL escape/sanitize that data or does Magento take care of doing so?

--
Here's a code example:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => 1, 'options' => array(5 =>$rawDataFromPost)));
$cart->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is properly sanitized and quoted. In fact the Zend framework does that, which Magento is built on.